# Oracle: How to use pivot muilti column?

Tags: oracle, pivot, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I want Pivot multi column. What use oracle pivot table?

**SQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * 
FROM IRO_SIM A  
WHERE A.COM_CODE = 'AAQ' 
AND A.PCODE = 'AKIOP'              
)
PIVOT
(
LISTAGG(SIMTYPE,',') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIMTYPE) 
FOR SIMTYPE IN ('H','V')
)
```

**Sample Data:**

```
COM_CODE | PCODE | L_VALUE | A_SIM | AMT_SIM | SIMTYPE
A        | AKIOP | 1700    | TOTAL | 50      | H
A        | AKIOP | 500     | EACH  | 100     | V

A        | BHUIO | 200     | TOTAL | 500     | H
A        | BHUIO | 600     | TOTAL | 400     | V
```

**i need Result:**

```
COM_CODE | PCODE | H_VALUE | H_ASIM | H_AMTSIM | V_VALUE | V_ASIM | V_AMTSIM
A        | AKIOP | 1700    | TOTAL  | 50       | 500     | EACH   | 100
A        | BHUIO | 200     | TOTAL  | 500      | 600     | TOTAL  | 400
```

thanks advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just list the multiple columns.  Every expression in your `PIVOT` clause will be matched with every value in the `FOR` clause.  So, what you want is this:

```
SELECT * FROM d
PIVOT ( sum(l_value) as value, max(a_sim) as asim, sum(amt_sim) as amtsim
        FOR simtype in ('H' AS "H", 'V' AS "V") )
```

With data...

```
with d as ( 
SELECT 'A' com_code, 'AKIOP' pcode, 1700 l_value, 'TOTAL' a_sim,  50 amt_sim, 'H' simtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' com_code, 'AKIOP' pcode,  500 l_value, 'EACH'  a_sim, 100 amt_sim, 'V' simtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' com_code, 'BHUIO' pcode,  200 l_value, 'TOTAL' a_sim, 500 amt_sim, 'H' simtype FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' com_code, 'BHUIO' pcode,  600 l_value, 'TOTAL' a_sim, 400 amt_sim, 'V' simtype FROM DUAL)
SELECT * FROM d
PIVOT ( sum(l_value) as value, max(a_sim) as asim, sum(amt_sim) as amtsim
    FOR simtype in ('H' AS "H", 'V' AS "V") )
```